# How to provide PHP script with the absolute path for file upload?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to develop a web application that uses  a third party API that requires the local file path of a video file for upload to their server(third party server).

Their PHP upload function requires the local path of a video file:

```
 public function upload($file_path)
```

My understanding is that I cannot get javascript to provide me with the local file path.  My questions is how do I go about providing the PHP script with this local file path for the video upload.

I know that I can upload the file to my own server using $_FILES['myfile']on the PHP side for instances, but since I am uploading to a third party server I need to get hold of the local file path.  Is there a solution for this?  I've been stuck on this problem for a few days and I am at a total loss.

Comment: You **can** get javascript to send a local file, as long as the user selects that file and confirms it. What you can't do is get the local path for that file, and it shouldn't matter either.

Comment: your question is not clear enough...here is my question: do you want to upload a file from your local server to their local server using their api or do you want to upload a file from their local server into their local path (basically a move operation in their local server)?

Comment: I am trying to upload a video file from my local computer(client computer) to their server - bypassing my server altogether.

Comment: And that's not a problem, XMLHttpRequest can send the file directly from the browser to any server you chose

Comment: @adeneo, please could you show me in code what you mean.  Obviously I can get the user to select a file with  "<input type="file">", but javascript only supplies the name of the file and not the path. Bear in mind that I need to use the 'upload(filepath)' function on the php side.

Comment: Javascript also supplies ***the*** file, which you then can send anywhere, as long the server you're sending it to allows cross domain calls.

Comment: @dave: just give the location of your file for the `path` argument...it is a string and nothing more....it can be a relative path (location of file is relative to your php script) or an absolute path....thats it....whats inside the api function is what you need to know and should be concerned about....